What electronic component is this? smd transistor mark "14LX"
14LX ，there is a horizontal line below.  What is the model of this device?


You should add more context: What is this part connected to? Show more of the circuit if you haven't traced it yourself. What kind of device is this from? Who is the manufacturer? What are the dimensions? Without any known visible parts next to it, it's hard to guess the package. The markings look a bit like Ablic, but seem to be missing the dots on top or below the marking text.

Next variant- Small Signal Diode 

The marking for your suggested part should be 'A1xM.' (https://i.sstatic.net/eADYSM0v.png)

@Velvet, not this

@曾庆明 I know, hence my comment.
